# Pattern Matching - Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for Regex Pattern extraction to extract the following example ,

```
sample Input: 
"USER 1-EFA-Thermal Analysis-0.25;USER 2-EFA-Thermal Analysis-0.25;"

 String[] parts = filename.split("\\;");
    for (int i=0;i<=parts.length;i++){

    }
```

The above code split the line into Multiple part with ";" as delimiter.
Inside the For Loop i want to again the split each part[] into three phrases which is identified by "-" (dash).But problem being the Dash can also appear within the field to be separated .

So my logic to is to split the Words Before First occurrence of "-" as 1st Part.

String After First Occurrence of "dash" till last occurrence of "dash" as 2nd
And the remaining being 3rd Part

For example :

```
part[0]
USER 1
EFA-Thermal Analysis
0.25

part[1]
USER 2
EFA-Thermal Analysis
0.25
```

Comment: "USER 1" is one combined word (Anything which appear before 1st occurence of "-"  is to be considered as First part of string

Comment: `But problem being the Dash can also appear within the field to be separated.` If you can assume that there are exactly 3 fields then it is solvable.

Comment: it is always Three "Parts" in each Phrase

Comment: so, is this exact pattern in every phrase ?

Comment: Yes , it will always be in same pattern

Comment: Should be easy then - strip by first "-" first, then strip the remaining by the last "-" (if you know there's not a dash in the last number there..)... and you have it

Comment: well, can you split `parts` like this `String []array = parts[i].split("-");` after that, you will have: `user 1, efa, thermal analysis, 0.25` and you can join array[1] and array[2] like this: `string efaThermal = array[1] + "-" + array[2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.split(string regex)` method will most likely not work, at least I cannot see how it can be used to achieve a relatively simple solution. The problem, in my opinion is that the dash can appear in between different character types which makes it tricky to latch onto.

I managed to achieve what you are after through a slightly different usage of regular expressions:

```
String str = "USER 1-EFA-Thermal Analysis-0.25;USER 2-EFA-Thermal Analysis-0.25;";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+?)-(.+?)-(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?);");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " " + matcher.group(2) + " " + matcher.group(3));
```

The code below yields the following information:

```
USER 1 EFA-Thermal Analysis 0.25
USER 2 EFA-Thermal Analysis 0.25
```

Which, according to the samples you have provided, should do what you are after. An example of the regular expression is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/aA3bU0/1).

Comment: It works perfect for my case , Thanks for the online website link too

Comment: It's possible with `split`, but it's not simple, and rely on the look-behind length check bug in Java: `"USER 1-EFA-Thermal Analysis-0.25".split("(?<=^[^-]*)-|-(?=[^-]*$)")`

Comment: @nhahtdh: I tried your expression and I got `USER 1`, `EFA-Thermal Analysis-0.25;USER 2-EFA-Thermal Analysis`, `0.25`. The problem in my opinion is that the dash you want to split on will not have the same position and will depend on what is happening before *and* after. I doubt that the result would be that maintainable. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @npinti: It's supposed to be used after splitting the initial string with `;`.

Comment: @nhahtdh: In that case it works. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex to match everything until the first "minus":

```
part.replaceAll("^([^\\-]*)-", "$1\n")
```

and everything from the last minus until the end of the string:

```
part.replaceAll("-([^\\-]*?)$", "\n$1")
```

**Code**

```
String sample = "USER 1-EFA-Thermal Analysis-0.25;USER 2-EFA-Thermal Analysis-0.25;";
String[] parts = sample.split("\\;");

for (String part : parts) {
    part = part.replaceAll("^([^\\-]*)-", "$1\n");
    part = part.replaceAll("-([^\\-]*?)$", "\n$1");
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

**Output**

```
USER 1
EFA-Thermal Analysis
0.25
USER 2
EFA-Thermal Analysis
0.25
```

[**Demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/p7C8hG)